Grub BADRAM doesn't blacklist special memory range
I have a laptop with a damaged integrated RAM, so I ran memtest86+ to get the affected sectors and marked them as unusable. The issue came when modifying the grub configuration. I set the GRUB_BADRAM option as
GRUB_BADRAM="0x086580000,0xffff80000,0x0bb1c0000,0xffff00000,0x0bfa40000,0xffffc0000"

Checking /proc/iomem I could see that no blacklist was being applied as it outputted the line
5f000000-dfffffff : Reserved

I decided to see the difference between the iomem file with no blacklist and the one with the BAD_RAM option and the only difference was the address where the kernel code was stored, which, as I am aware, is decided at random on every boot, so there was no effective difference at all. Also, I was still experiencing the same memory related troubles as before, where some programs would crash due to a SIGSEGV, even my Desktop Environment or GCC.
Thinking I did something wrong, I chose to change the memory addresses to 4 GB later (starting at address 0x186580000 and so on)
and to my surprise it did block them, as I could see
186580000-1865fffff : Unusable memory
186600000-1bb0fffff : System RAM
1bb100000-1bb1fffff : Unusable memory
1bb200000-1bfa3ffff : System RAM
1bfa40000-1bfa7ffff : Unusable memory
1bfa80000-41f33ffff : System RAM

So this time the change was being applied.
All of this makes me question, was the first blacklist happening at all? Was iomem just not showing the blacklist range due to some hierarchy? Or even, is there some range that cannot be affected by GRUB_BADRAM?

dmesg of early boot? which boot mode (secure boot, uefi, dos)? which kernel parameters (/proc/cmdline)? Grub badram does not work in all cases. You can try memmap=. /proc/iomem will not list individual offsets if it's already part of a larger reserved region. If you still have issues then this reserved region is being used anyway, or other regions are bad too. Not directly related but you can also try memtest=17 parameter (if your kernel has CONFIG_MEMTEST=y, and its a very simple pattern test, so memory has to be very reliably bad for it to work) as well as run memtester in user space.
